# Angular: empty initial value of an element

Tags: angular

I have the input like that:

```
<input name="inputVal1" type="number" [(ngModel)]="struct1.val1"/>
```

So a client gets "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'val1' of undefined" because struct1 is not initialized at the beginning. It's not initialized because I do not need that the input has initial value I need only empty field at beginning. struct1.val1 value could be changed by other elements. So how to implement it in the right way?

Comment: i am not sure what you want but you can try this`[(ngModel)]="{{struct1?.val1}}"`

Comment: AndrejB you can define `struct1` and its value to use initially in `component`

Answer (score 0):

So, modified type of struct1, now it's always initialized. Thanks to all.